# Unresolved dependency peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@2.1.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I was trying to run a react project. React and Node version Installed:

- React: 18.1.0
- Node: 16.15.1
- Package manager: npm v 8.12.1
- OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

  Any help in resolving the errors will be appreciated!

````
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: cbioportal-frontend@3.3.182
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.55.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"^5.55.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"*" from bootstrap-loader@1.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/bootstrap-loader
npm ERR!     bootstrap-loader@"^1.2.0-beta.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@2.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!   css-loader@"^2.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer css-loader@"*" from bootstrap-loader@1.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/bootstrap-loader
npm ERR!     bootstrap-loader@"^1.2.0-beta.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and now it is working for me first check the version on the node by executing this command `node -v` and if you don't have this node versions `v12.22.12` install it by executing this command `nvm install 12.22.12` and then use this node only by executing this command `nvm use 12.22.12` and then restart your terminal(close all terminal) and then start

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error message, there is dependency conflict between `css-loader@^2.1.1"` and `webpack@^4.0.0`.

Try `npm uninstall --save-dev css-loader webpack` to uninstall the dependencies entirely.

Then reinstall them with `npm install --save-dev css-loader webpack`.

Hopefully, there won't be any dependency conflict with the latest versions, but if so, try `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: On running the uninstall command, I got another set of errors. 

`Could not resolve dependency:
peer webpack@"^1.9.11" from extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
peer extract-text-webpack-plugin@"<2.0.0" from bootstrap-loader@1.3.3
node_modules/bootstrap-loader
bootstrap-loader@"^1.2.0-beta.1" from the root project`

Comment: Try to run npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: If that doesn't work, try to run npm cache clear --force and then run npm install --legacy-peer-deps. Finally, if nothing of above mentioned solutions work, delete node modules and package.json file, and try to run npm install --force